# If a computer is under the shared header in Finder, can they access all the files on my computer?

Tags: finder

This is a pretty basic question, but I noticed I have two other computers under the shared header in finder, can they access all files on my computer?  How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Shared folders are controlled by the “Sharing” preference pane in System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The list shows other Macs that have "shared" their files to you, not the other way round.